# Single Cycle Datapath Write to Register and Memory at Same Time

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture, circuit, circuit-diagram

Is it possible to alter a single-cycle datapath so that an add instruction not only writes to a register, but also writes to a specified memory address?  The only way I can think to do this is to split the value as shown bellow.  I don't think this is possible though.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this idea is how to specify both the destination register number and a memory address in a single 32 bit instruction word.

One of the basic principles of [RISC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_instruction_set_computing) architecture is for each instruction to only have one output result. This makes tricks like piplelining and super-scalar execution much easier to manage. CISC architectures like the PDP-11 and the x86 had instructions with multiple output results, and this made them much harder to design to run fast.